# StaticResource and DynamicResource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently browsing WPF examples on [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Data%20Binding/SimpleBinding) GitHub. This one is a simple application - it binds a textbox to a label. Whenever the textbox's text changes, the label is changed too via a data binding.

Now, I'm reading a StaticResource is evaluated the moment the XAML object is constructed and cannot be changed later, while a DynamicResource is evaluated each time it is accessed.

In this program, it would seem to me DynamicResources should be used, however only two StaticResources are present.

Here is what I'd deem the crucial code:

```
// ...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Person x:Key="MyDataSource" PersonName="Joe"/>
    </Window.Resources>
// ...
            <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyDataSource}" Path="PersonName"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <Label>The name you entered:</Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDataSource}, Path=PersonName}"/>
```

How come it works with StaticResources?

Comment: The object referenced by `StaticResource MyDataSource` does not change, just the value of its PersonName property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Clemens,

> The object referenced by StaticResource MyDataSource does not change, just the value of its PersonName property.